# Google sheets apps script Onformsubmit trigger function does not allow accessing file using driveapp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently trying to have a user submit a form which contains a csv on which i have to process information. To do this i created a function which would parse the file uploaded and then I would write the same to either a helper file or in a new sheet within the form responses spreadsheet. Issue is that when I try to access the csv uploaded using the file ID I get the error below. I have read a few similar issues where they mention that the trigger onformsubmit cannot give these permissions and to add the file processing function a a custom menu but that would lead to a more time consuming workflow

*Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)

Code for onformsubmit is given below

```
function onFormSubmit(e){

  //Logger.log('item1' + e.namedValues['Billing data file'][0]);
  //Logger.log('item2' + e.namedValues['Billing data file']);
  let billingFilelink = e.namedValues['Billing data file'][0];
  let billingFileId = billingFilelink.split("?id=")[1];

  let file = DriveApp.getFileById("1Mg3X7xdhTUJ5N6nMR2nB5tto2F7xCUUc");
  importCSVFromGoogleDrive(billingFileId)
  //Logger.log(billingFileId)
}
```

here the file ID i manually added in but it would actually be billingFileId. If there is a simpler way to do this it would be great to get a suggestion

The file with script is shared below

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T8Rh90-_wC86R7gvTjIOH8sas5Nz5CuGUHWz2Zv5D2I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried to add the scope to the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here. First, per the first comment, you could add the scopes to a manual list in the project manifest, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes). You just need to include any/all scopes the project uses, including the one mentioned in the error. Second, I often find that when I run the `onFormSubmit` function within the actual Apps Script editor, even though the function won't be able to fully execute, it often is able to get the full list of scopes and have you approve them in that way. That would be the simpler option, so I'd try that first and if it fails, give the first method a go.

Comment: adding scopes to the manifest worked. thanks

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

*Adding more information to the answer already provided*

Since you never ran the script nor added the scopes to the manifest, this is the expected behavior as you didn't authorize the application itself. Google cannot do that on your behalf, so in order to solve your error you can indeed add the scopes (
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`) to the manifest, like mentioned above.

As for the second option, you can simply create an empty function:

```
function myFunction() {
}
```

And run this function from the script. In this way you will end up receiving the consent screen and the script will be authorized as needed.

You might also need to bear in mind that the `onFormSubmit` trigger is an **installable** one, so you will have to set it up first before using it.

#### Reference

- [OAuth Client Verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification);
- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).